# How to get callback from esp so that I can know which light is turned on

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm using[flutter blue plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) and when I apply the `read.characteristic()` I get either the ESP32(I get data in list but it's conversion in string) or [0,0], how to know the status that this particular led is turned on.
I'm able to write succefully on ESP.

[ESP](https://www.electronicscomp.com/esp32-development-board-with-wifi-bluetooth-india?gclid=Cj0KCQiA8t2eBhDeARIsAAVEga2yBNAZjTNQXtm_S3EzXYqutfhrg0SIoqHfFkz822RcVU1UwF0COIAaAtu8EALw_wcB)

[[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rruFW.png)]

I'm trying to implement this using flutter blue [image from](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
characteristic.value.listen((value) {
    // do something with new value
       print(value)              // this value have all data from device
});
```

this code provides values from the device the main problem in my case was I wasn't able to figure out which one provide me with that callback, lol it was so easy.